# Ssh load key error: invalid format

Tags: windows-10, ssh, ssh-keys

After one of the recent Windows 10 updates on my laptop I'm getting ssh error in Cmder and Hyper:

```
Load key "C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
```

It worked OK before that.

To fix it I've tried to generate new keys, and paste the contents of the old ones, but it didn't help.

The same keys work OK while using ssh in Git Bash.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: [please checkout this sovled question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863913/key-load-public-invalid-format)

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling too - the solution is simple! Add an extra line in your key at the end of the file.

Yes, that's simple! I don't know why the VSCode Remote SSH extension (@ext:ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh) requires it, but after I add an extra line to my key, autologin start working with no issues.

I was trying to work with the format of the line (eg Linux vs Windows), but my current config is:

```
Host remote-linux
  HostName 192.168.0.2
  User username
  IdentityFile ~\.ssh\id-rsa
```

But id-rsa should have an extra empty line at the end:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
bN9GIVNs6PragmuRv04pfGHz0HVxdJNeSYlaYqsOYh...
...
nUYVnI+gPnlMjDeDXIQZtxM28MGBC27szzZmU8...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

^extra line
```

Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859437/windows-10-openssh-key-invalid-format

PS: It's interesting if Windows 11 has the same issue or not...
PPS: my key is CRLF, originally it was LF.